# Determine if a list of dictionaries has equivalent value

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to find out that the following list of dictionaries has equivalent score number?

```
sorted_list = [
   {
      "team":"team",
      "score":2,
      "matches":3,
      "goal_difference":2
   },
   {
      "team":"team",
      "score":2,
      "matches":3,
      "goal_difference":3
   },
   {
      "team":"team",
      "score":1,
      "matches":3,
      "goal_difference":-1
   },
   {
      "team":"team",
      "score":4,
      "matches":3,
      "goal_difference":3
   }
]
```

For example in the above list `sorted_list[0].score == sorted_list[1].score`. I will sort this list differently depending on the values. `score` has the highest priority, then `goal_differences` and then `matches`

```
if list has equivalent score numbers:
    sorted_list = sorted(sorted_list , key=lambda k: k['goal_differences'])
else if list has equivalent goal_differences:
    sorted_list = sorted(sorted_list , key=lambda k: k['matches'])
else sorted_list = sorted(sorted_list , key=lambda k: k['score'])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an appropriate key function:

```
from operator import itemgetter

sorted(sorted_list, key=itemgetter('score', 'goal_difference', 'matches'))
```

If you want some special logic like higher score first, lower matches first, build your own key:

```
sorted(sorted_list, key=lambda d: (-d['score'], -d['goal_difference'], d['matches']))
```

Comment: Thank you. You did even better, no ifs :) . Works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

`How to find out that the following list of dictionaries has equivalent score number?`

```
len(set([x["score"] for x in sorted_list])) == 1
```